# Select value from a list of columns that is close to another value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following data frame:

```
S0  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5... Price
10  15  18  12  18  19     16
55  45  44  66  58  45     64
77  84  62  11  61  44     20
```

I want to create another column `Sup` which stores one value lower than the `Price`.
Intended result:

```
S0  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5... Price  Sup
10  15  18  12  18  19     16    15
55  45  44  66  58  45     64    58
77  84  62  11  61  44     20    11
```

Here's what I have been trying:

```
s = np.sort(df.filter(like='S').values, axis=1)
mask = (s*1.03) > df['Close'].values[:,None]
df['Sup'] = np.where(mask.any(1), s[np.arange(s.shape[0]),mask.argmax(1)], 0)
```

If the difference is greater than 3% it doesn't do the job right. Note that the s columns may vary so I would want to keep the `np.sort(df.filter(like='S').values, axis=1)`

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: You seem to conflict yourself where you want to *stores one value lower than the Price* but your code check for `one value larger than Price/1.03`

Comment: I did change the sign to < and removed the *1.03 as well but it still doesn't do the job right for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df.filter(like='S')

# compare to the price
mask = s.lt(df['Price'], axis=0)

# `where(mask)` places `NaN` where mask==False
# `max(1)` takes maximum along rows, ignoring `NaN`
# rows with all `NaN` returns `NaN` after `max`, 
# `fillna(0)` fills those with 0
df['Price'] = s.where(mask).max(1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   S0  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Price
0  10  15  18  12  18  19   15.0
1  55  45  44  66  58  45   58.0
2  77  84  62  11  61  44   11.0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. One question tho, if i am to find the next big value do I put min instead of max? i tried but that doesn't work

Comment: You also need to change `gt` to `lt` for less than, in creation of `mask`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would get the job done:

```
p = df['Price']
m = df.filter(like='S').lt(p, axis=0)
df['Sup'] = df[m].max(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Updated, maybe this will work better for you.

Comment: thanks for the help but it spits out an error. The other solution works